# Reversing a word : C++

Tags: c++, char, reverse

I want to reverse a char string in c++.
I wrote this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char word[80] = "polymorphism";
    char rev[80];
    int i, j;
    int l;
    l = strlen(word);
    for(i = 0, j = l; i < l-1; i++, j--){
        word[j] = rev[i];
    }
    cout << rev << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In terminal it shows some characters like this:

```
83???uH??? ... Something like this
```

Comment: Step through with a debugger. Find which single operation doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: use `char rev[80] = "";` to avoid those funny characters...

Comment: I guess you want `j = l-1` in for loop's initialization.

Comment: without a debugger, use a pen-and-pencil and see exactly what's going on, it shouldn't be too hard

Comment: @vsoftco I think that it is more reliable to use a hammer-and-nails.

Comment: `std::string word = "polymorphism"; std::reverse(std::begin(word), std::end(word)); std::cout << word << '\n';`. You're coding in "C with std::cout", instead of C++. That's like walking with a Ferrari.

Comment: Use std::reverse and std::string instead of the ugly char []. If you must create an array of chars, at least make it a pointer to char.

Answer (score 3):

Your character array rev is not zero terminated.

And istead of to write to rev you are writing to word.:)

```
    word[j] = rev[i];
```

The loop is also wrong due to condition

```
i < l-1;
```

There must be

```
i < l;
```

The program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char word[80] = "polymorphism";
    char rev[80];

    size_t n = std::strlen( word );

    size_t i = 0;
    for ( ; i < n; i++ ) rev[i] = word[n - i - 1];
    rev[i] = '\0';

    std::cout << word << std::endl;
    std::cout << rev << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
polymorphism
msihpromylop
```

Take into account that you can do the same using standard algorithm `std::reverse_copy` declared in header `<algorithm>`.
For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    char word[80] = "polymorphism";
    char rev[80];

    size_t n = std::strlen( word );

    *std::reverse_copy( word, word + n, rev ) = '\0';

    std::cout << word << std::endl;
    std::cout << rev << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as above

```
polymorphism
msihpromylop
```

Comment: why not just `char rev[80] ="";` and `std::reverse_copy( word, word + n, rev );`

Comment: @vsoftco Because I consider a general approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char word[80] = "polymorphism";
    char rev[80] = {'\0'};
    int i = 0;
    int last = strlen(word) - 1;
    while(last >= 0) {
        rev[i] = word[last];
        i++;
        last--;
    }
    cout << rev << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `l` is not declared anywhere. Also you are missing an open curly brace after `while(last >= 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 changes I made to your code: 
Change 1: Since string length is `l`, indexing will be from `0` t o`l-1`.
Change 2: `rev` will be storing the values from `word`, not the other way round.
Change 3: A proper string should be `\0` terminated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
char word[80] = "polymorphism";
char rev[80]="";
int i, j;
int l;
l = strlen(word);
for(i = 0, j = l-1; i < l; i++, j--){    //change 1
    rev[i] = word[j];                     // change 2   
}
rev[i]='\0';          // change 3 

cout<<rev;
return 0;
}
```

Working ideone link: http://ideone.com/kIqeNF

Comment: When i is equal to l j is equal to -1.

Comment: Can you explain me the `rev[i] = '\0'`?

Comment: @Sakir: In C, strings should be Null Terminated. This means that a proper string should end with the Null character `\0`, to actually be treated as a proper string.

Comment: So `rev[i]` means the last index of the `rev` array?

Comment: @Sakir: Yes, it does.